# Current device language is not getting updated in iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mobile, ios11

On Fresh install the app is taking the current device language

If user selects any different language(Spanish, German, polish etc.,) from application and wishes to switch back to device language.

[nslocale currentlocale]]localeidentifier] or [nslocale autoupdatingcurrentlocale]]localeidentifier] or systemlocale methods not returning the current device language instead it is returning the last selected language by the user from the application.

Answer (score 0):

I used NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0].contains("XX")....